# Can I add a junit test case at runtime?

Tags: java, junit

I have a test procedure that need to test lots of `xml` templates.

But I found that i have to write a test case for each `xml` template.

Does junit have such a mechanism that I can produce another test case inside one test case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [@Parameterized](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests). This will give you what you want. Here is a simple case, to run a test for all files in a single directory:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ParameterizedTest {
    @Parameters(name = "{index}: file {0}")
    public static Iterable<Object[]> data() {
        File[] files = new File("/temp").listFiles();

        List<Object[]> objects = new ArrayList<Object[]>(files.length);

        for (File file : files) {
            objects.add(new Object[] { file.getAbsolutePath() });
        }

        return objects;
    }

    private final String filename;

    public ParameterizedTest(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("test filename=" + filename);
    }
}
```

Each test in the file is run once for each entry in the list returned by `data()`. You can obviously do what you want with the files, but if you're constructing the list of tests dynamically, then you'll need to have some way of constructing the pass/fail criteria also. So, if you're transforming lots of xml into other xml, then you'll need the resulting xml available as well, maybe in a different directory or with a different (but predictable) name.

Comment: How to run this with 'mvn test' ?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no "test case inside a test case" type functionality -- other than loops!

Loops to the rescue!

```
@Test
public void xmlShouldBeValid() {
    String[] templates = new String[]{ TEMPLATE1, TEMPLATE2, TEMPLATE3 };
    for (String template : templates) {
        testTemplate(template);
    }
}

private void testTemplate(String template) {
    assertEquals("whatever", template);
}
```

Something like this might help. Another trick I use a lot is to make helper assert* methods. So if I'm checking that the XML has 3 attributes a, b, and c, I might write

```
private void assertTemplate(String template, String a, String b, int c) {
    String aFromTemplate = parseAfromTemplate(template); // normally this is done inline
    String bFromTemplate = parseBfromTemplate(template); // but a function to read easier
    String cFromTemplate = parseCfromTemplate(template);
    assertEquals(a, aFromTemplate);
    assertEquals(b, bFromTemplate);
    assertEquals(c, cFromTemplate);
}
```

Now you can call assertTemplate multiple times in one test function:

```
@Test
public void xmlShouldBeValid() {
    assertTemplate("<hardcoded xml object>", "a", "b", "c");
    assertTemplate("<hardcoded xml object>", "r", "s", "t");
    assertTemplate("<hardcoded xml object>", "x", "y", "z");
}
```

Of course, instead of using String for the type of template, substitute the XML object for whatever framework (if any) you're using.